# Series Error when using .dtypes() for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I am relatively new to Python / Pandas and I am trying to print out the type of values for each column in my data frame. However, when I try to use the .dtypes() function I am getting a series error.

Here is some of the code I am using:

```
file = pd.read_csv('Nudge.csv', sep=",")


data = pd.DataFrame({'SR_ID': file['SR ID'], 'On_Time_%': file['On-Time %'], '#_Tardy': file['# Unex Tardy'],
'Tardy_Rank': file['Tardy Rank']})


new_data = data.sort_values(by='On_Time_%', ascending=True)
# print(new_data)
print(data.dtypes())


TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

dtypes is not a function rather a variable. It should be called like this,

```
print(data.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `data.dtypes` instead of `data.dtypes()`, as it is an attribute and no function.

This will return something like:

```
ID        object
Year      object
Month     object
Amount    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Goof on my part, thank you!